# How to connect one entity with more than one entity in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have some problems in understanding how to connect one entity with others in one attribute. That is not typical OneToMany relationship, I'm talking about situation when I need to implement complains functionality in my application: `User` can complain about several different entities (`Question`, `Answer`, `Comment` or another `User`), so the `Complain` entity will have schema relations like:
[image: schema]

where User connects as One to many to `user_id` and Many To One to `entity_id` (`1` to `*` and `*` to `1` in image).

So, I tried to use parameterized class `Complain` to implement this (`BaseComplain` is empty class):

`Complain.java`

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "complains")
public class Complain<T extends BaseComplain> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_id", nullable = false)
    private T entity_id;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created_on;

}
```

`User.java`

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseComplain {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user_id", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Complain<BaseComplain>> author_complains;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity_id", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Complain<User>> complains;

    <...other stuff...>
}
```

And `Question.java` (all entities have the same realisation of relationship):

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question extends BaseComplain {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity_id", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Complain<Question>> complains;
    
    <...other stuff...>
}
```

But it caused (formatted):

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: 
Property com.*.*.Entities.Complain.entity_id has an unbound type and no explicit target entity.
Resolve this Generic usage issue or set an explicit target attribute (eg @OneToMany(target=)
or use an explicit @Type...
```

I can add all stack trace, but there are only typical spring app exceptions (`Bean creation error`, `embedded Tomcat exception`).

**So the question is - Is there any way to implement this logics using only, like, "basic" features of JPA?**

Probably, I have some ideas of `@MappedSuperclass` usage, but still need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this - it looks like what you have tried to a certain extent; the idea is that the `Complaint` is an abstract base entity, so that it can have relations to and from it, but the concrete implementations are questions, answers etc. To have a base table and separate ones per complaint type, use `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)`. And use concrete complaint types that are different from the entities they link to, e.g. `QuestionComplaint` → `Question`. So:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "complaints")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Complaint {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date created_on;
}
```

The user in turn relates to a set of `Complaint` objects, but is not a `Complaint` itself (doesn't make sense, does it?)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user_id", orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Complaint> complaints;
}
```

And the concrete `Complaint` instances:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "question_complaints")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
public class QuestionComplaint extends Complaint {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Question question
}
```

This entity represents the link from `Complaint` to `Question`. The `Question` entity, which represents a "Question", no matter if it has complaints attached, may optionally have a relation back to the `QuestionComplaint`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "question")
    private List<QuestionComplaint> complaints;
}
```

Now usages I expect would be:

1. What are the complaints filed by a user? - `User.getComplaints()` will fetch a UNION ALL of the complaints from all known subtypes
2. What are the complaints attachede to a question (answer, etc)? - `question.getComplaints()` knows to get records only from the table `question_complaints`
3. What complaints has user x filed for question y? - `SELECT c FROM QuestionComplaint c WHERE c.user.id = :x AND c.question.id = :y`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is pretty elegant solution) To be honest, my first idea was about `Complain` as a join-table with complex custom logics in all `*ComplainableEntity*Service` components. Thank you very much for detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Fistly, in java `Generic Types` can't deteminable in `runtime`, so `JPA` can't determine to fetch from which `table`, so it will `throw Exception` which you send.

Secodly your database design is wrong, `Complain` table will not connect to `Question` and `Answer`, `Question` and `Answer` need to connect `Complain`. Like:

```
Quesiton -|
          v
          ---> Complain ---> User
          ^
Answer   -|
```

Or you need to add to two fields to `Complain` table like `questionId` and `answerId`.

```
Q u e s i t o n    A n s w e r 
       ^               ^
       |               |
  (questionID)     (answerId)    
       |               |
       +-----------Complain ---> User
```

One field two foreign table not good design specially for JPA.

Comment: Thanks for explanation about `Generic Types`  runtime determination, pretty useful information for further dev. About the database - that is some kind of university side-project with partly-given db structure, that's why me and my friends are trying to make it effective and clean. Anyway, thank you!